Stolen Bike, Met the current owner of it, need help with what to do next
this all literally just happened so forgive me if I miss out some important information or if things are jumbled but I will keep it short.
My bike got stolen 3 days ago in London, and after that, I was on ebay, facebook and other sites looking for my bike just in case it got posted online. I reported to the police, and in classic UK fashion they said that they can't do anything about it as I dont have the serial number. 11 hours after the incident, the exact same bike with the same damage was posted on ebay and the seller gave me his exact address to sell the bike cash only. The address was 8 minutes away from my home. With all that, we agreed to a time to collect the bike and my plan was to scare him with the police to potentially get the bike back. Well it did not go to plan today as his dad came out and told him to go in and just defended him the entire time saying he bought it off someone, which I do believe as he showed me the other account selling the bike. I also managed to take a picture of the sticker on the bike frame with the serial number before I left.
My question is, can I now use that serial number to the police as the serial number for the bike, or will they be funny about it and try say I am claiming someone else's bike. I just have so much good evidence in my opinion that the bike is mine, there is CCTV outside where the bike was stolen, there is CCTV outside his house from his neighbours so the bike getting to his house must have been recorded. I now have the serial number too. Is it all hopeless or is there another route I can take.
Not very short so thank you for reading. Hopefully I can get some guidance on all of this.

I’m voting to close this question because it required legal advice and only loosely replated to bicycles.

As far as 'using' the serial number, IANAL, I imagine deceiving the Police with regards how you know it would be a crime.

I had a bike stolen in Lincoln UK and eventually successfully recovered with some help from police ~ 1.5 months later. To my surprise police never asked for the frame serial number (which I had).

Key piece of information missing from your original post: How did you acquire that bike? Did you buy it new from the shop? Do you have a proof of purchase? Bike shop could help you by looking up a frame serial number and helping to reliably link it to your purchase. An evidence that police will not be able to dismiss.

@mattnz It's probably a subject for a separate discussion but I do think bicycle theft has some has some specifics that make it largely a subject of it's own. In terms of things you can steal and then use to get away, I believe bicycle thefts are far more numerous than motorbike or car thefts. In terms of things that o lot of people have, and often have values in the hundreds of GBP/USD, I believe you're more likely to buy a bike for cash than a mobile phone, and therefore more likely to struggle to prove ownership.

@mattnz in any case, how about migrating it to legal stack exchange, rather than closing altogether?

Yes, sorry that the question wasn't too bike related, just wanted to try get some answers. I appreciate the help tho. @mattnz

@ArtGertner I bought it from decathlon, brand new in 2021. We have the receipt of the bike. I emailed decathlon asking for help but they said that unless we registered the bike with them they don't store that type of information, so now I'm just at a loss on what to do.

Do you have some kind of house contents insurance, bike might be covered?

The first idea that comes to my mind is definitely get in touch with the police again immediately (I would probably try the non emergency 101 number first, but might be tempted to even try 999 if the former is unhelpful), tell them all of the above.
It doesn't sound right that they can't do anything because you didn't originally have the serial number number but I can't read up on it at the moment.
They certainly should have both the power and the interest to extract information from the people currently trying to sell the bike. It's just speculation but I can't help wondering whether the people currently trying to sell it are part of a network flogging stolen bikes - a term that comes to mind is "bike laundering".
I seriously hope they gave you a call/log id for your first call, if they did then make sure you quote that, if they didn't then at least get one this time.
Keep note of as much detail as possible: that address etc, a description of the person you spoke to etc, you might get asked for it.
Take screenshots of the advert with the seller's user id etc.
In any case good luck, I did once recover a beloved vintage bike in some fairly similar circumstances.

Hi thanks for answering, I am also quite confident that its a scheme as the dad was very very defensive and telling his son to go inside and not talk. We also have it on video of him saying his son sells many bikes, and I even have the account and store location of said original seller. I will contact them tomorrow and update them on all the info and also provide the new serial number, its just that im worried that if I tell them we got the serial number from them technically, that the bike is just theirs now? Unless they will go and check cameras and stuff.

It also is just super suspicious that this all happened within 24 hours. He managed to find a bike on sale for super cheap, and then sell it on for a bit more. Their excuse was he didn't like the bike? So odd.

Yes, selling a bike straight away after buying it is a big red flag. Especially if his son "sells many bikes". There's certainly something shady going on. Not sure how to proceed unless you want to buy your own bike back.

Most countries you do not need to be the one stealing to break the law. The concept that "Receiving Stolen goods" being illegal is pretty widespread.
